# Symfony2/Doctrine joined query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to create a simple query that produces a result set of a database entry plus the username of the person that posted it.

I've tried to setup the associations properly but I'm not sure if that's right either.  I'm finding the whole idea of using these small string identifiers quite confusing.  Surely there must be a simpler way of doing a join?

My two entities:

```
class Users
{
  // ...

  /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Titles", mappedBy="addedBy")
    */
    protected $username;

   // ..
}
```

and

```
class Titles
{
    // ....

    /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="username")
     */
     protected $addedBy;

    // ....
}
```

with the following in the controller:

```
$titles = $em->createQueryBuilder()
             ->select('t.*', 'u.*')
             ->from('dvdLoggerdvdBundle:Titles', 't')
             ->leftJoin('t.addedBy', 'u')
             ->addOrderBy('t.title', 'DESC')
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 69 near 'u ORDER BY t.title': Error: Class 
dvdLogger\dvdBundle\Entity\Titles has no association named addedBy `
```

**Update 1**

I made all the changes suggested by Tom and did lots of reading!

It appears that in order to overcome the lazy loading feature I need to carry out a leftJoin.  I have rewritten my query as follows:

```
public function getAllTitles()
{
    // view all records in db
    $titles = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t, u')
        ->leftJoin('t.addedBy', 'u')
        ->addOrderBy('t.title', 'DESC');

    return $titles->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

I am getting a result set, but the `addedBy` is returning NULL when I dump the result set.  As far as I'm aware shouldn't this pull the associated field in from the other table?

Comment: I suspect that you are just trying to get the username without the rest of the user object? Not going to happen.  Doctrine is an Object Relation Manager and as such it expects to use objects.  So you grab the titles and join the user.  You would then use: $title->getAddedBy()->getUsername();  Work through the Product/Category example in the documentation:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html to get a basic understanding os what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Cerad, your right.. I need to realign my head quite a bit. I'll have a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to reference the entity by its id, you are trying to reference it using the username. The inversed field should also be a specific field not an existing one that holds data. And keep it mind this field is optional and defines the associations as bidirectional, for the specified use case you don't actually need it as you are joining from the Titles entity. I would advice reading the doc here  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations as well as here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

## **Bidirectional association (w/ inversed field)**

First get rid of that line:

```
  @ORM\Column(type="string")
```

In your `$addedBy` annotations and change `inverseBy="username"` to `inversedBy="titles"` (note the typo)

You optionaly could add

`@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

Then in your Users Entity add

```
  /**
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Titles", mappedBy="addedBy")
    */
    protected $titles;
```

And get rid of

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Titles", mappedBy="addedBy")
```

In your `$username` annotations

Last make sure you update the database schema

Then your query should return the expected result.

## **Unidirectional association (w/out inversed field)**

Get rid of

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Titles", mappedBy="addedBy")
```

In your `$username` annotations

Then get rid of that line in your `$addedBy` annotations:

```
  @ORM\Column(type="string")
```

As well as  `inverseBy="username"`

You optionaly could add

`@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

Last make sure you update the database schema

Then your query should return the expected result.

Comment: excellent answer, many thanks Tom. Am I right in thinking that the query now doesnt need the `join` method? and that the results from the 2nd table are only returned if requested?

Comment: Yes you are right but do keep in mind that Doctrine has different fetch modes when retrieving entities. While you can indeed use the default "LAZY" mode on a one-to-many association it will make numerous small requests (basically each first time you request an associated entity) so it's - generally - more suited for prototyping. Using "JOIN" clauses in your queries or setting the fetch mode to "EAGER" (on doctrine 2.5+) will get all results in one bigger request.

Comment: yes, its been interesting to get my head around the lazy loading idea when all Ive seen before is the more instant sql methods of retrieval. Ill have a look at the 'eager' mode, Ive not come across that yet.